# Java switch statement using final method parameter

Tags: java

This java method doesn't compile. It allows newName but not lastName. Can anyone explain why? Thanks!

```
void doStuff(String firstName, final String lastName)
{
    final String newName = "John";
    switch(firstName)
    {
    case newName:
    case lastName:
    }
}
```

Comment: `"Can anyone explain why? "` -- the compiler can, what error message is it showing you?

Comment: `lastName` can vary at runtime.  `newName` cannot.  Case labels must be compile-time constants.

Comment: The compile says that case statements must be constant. In this code, lastName and newName are both constant, yet the compiler allows newName but not lastName.

Comment: Oh I see. They must be compile-time constants. Got it, thanks!